# sort floating numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, math, frontend

How can I sort this in javascript...?
so, it should 1st campare the 1st element and sort accordingly and if it finds the both elements are same it should consider 2rd element and sort it and so on...

```
 items = [[1,0,1294.099,369.3032],[1,0.892948,1272.855,1581.262],[0,0,220.9667,369.3032],[0,0.892948,228.0871,1581.262]]
```

I tried doing this but it doesn't work...

```
 items = [[1,0,1294.099,369.3032],[1,0.892948,1272.855,1581.262],[0,0,220.9667,369.3032],[0,0.892948,228.0871,1581.262]]


  items.sort((a,b)=>{
     if(a > b) return 1;
     else if(b > a) return -1;
     else return 0;
  })
```

It should sort in asscending order...

Comment: What is the sort order you want? Ascending or descending?

Comment: in asscending order.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```js
items = [[1,0,1294.099,369.3032],[1,0.892948,1272.855,1581.262],[0,0,220.9667,369.3032],[0,0.892948,228.0871,1581.262]]

const comp = (a, b) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
    else if(a[i] < b[i]) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

console.log(items.sort(comp));
```